# How to capture method arguments sent to a stubbed method using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Here's my stubbed method:

```
 Mockito.when(restTemplateMock.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK));
```

How can I grab hold of the argument sent to this method? The above `postForEntity` method has 3 arguments.

Comment: `ArgumentCaptor`.

Comment: @chrylis I've been looking into ArgumentCaptor documentation but unable to figure out how to capture each of those 3 arguments https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.3.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#captors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final ArgumentCaptor<String> arg1Captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
final ArgumentCaptor<Object> arg2Captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
final ArgumentCaptor<Class<?>> arg3Captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Class.class);

Mockito.verify(restTemplateMock).postForEntity(arg1Captor, arg2Captor, arg3Captor);

Assert.assertEquals("Whatever", arg1Captor.getValue());
```